# How long do I need to wait before I can activate Steam keys again?

Tags: steam

I was [activating some Steam keys](https://store.steampowered.com/account/registerkey) I got from a game bundle when Steam threw an error:

> There have been too many recent activation attempts from this account or Internet address. Please wait and try your product code again later.

I've waited a few minutes but I'm still getting the error. How long do I need to wait before I can activate Steam codes again?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/2254560552290330923/) and [this thread](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/2254560552290315498/), the cooldown is around 30 minutes.

Steam doesn't seem to have an official timer listed anywhere, but this problem has been encountered many times since at least 2020, and every thread I've come across references a similar 30 minute cool down.

Comment: I can anecdotally confirm 30 minutes.

Comment: Note that it can happen again after the first 30 minutes of cooldown. When it happens a second time, the cooldown is still 30 minutes. Source: Had the problem my self